# Curly brackets when populating widget from database

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to figure out how to prevent the { } brackets from displaying when I query the database and the widget is populated. I realize it be because there is a space between the words but I am not sure how to prevent the brackets from displaying.

I have tried to look for an answer through search engines but I have not been successful in finding anything regarding how to resolve this from occurring.

For each column in the table is queried and it displays an open bracket at the beginning of the data population and a close bracket at the end of it.

Example of a population in widget:

{Buffalo City}

{Miami City}

{Florida}

Each of the results are from a different row_id but out of the same table and column.
If there is no space between the 2 words (BuffaloCity), there is no brackets and if the words are tied by an underscore (Buffalo_City), there is also no brackets.

Is there a doc I can read to know how to resolve and prevent this from happening?

My query:

```
selection = var.get()
c.execute('SELECT Recipe FROM Recipes WHERE Dish_Type = :selection ORDER BY Recipe DESC', {"selection": selection})
results = c.fetchall()
for each_result in results:
    output.insert(0,each_result)
```

Comment: Did you try to `join` the result first?

Comment: I am not familiar with that, can you explain it?

Comment: You are most likely passing an tuple to your widget. You can `join` the results to a string first by `"".join(result_from_db)`

Comment: I will give this a try, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Henry Yik, I have tried to use this but being reasonably new I am not having success. The ".join" should be used after the query and after the results = c.fetchall(), is that correct?  I have edited my original question to show the query.

Comment: Show your `print (results)` output as well.

Comment: I have resolved the issue by modifying the insert line from output.insert(0, each_result) to output.insert(0, each_result[0])

Answer (score 0):

You handle DB results like this:

```
for each_result in results:
    output.insert(0, each_result)
```

I recommend renaming the variable to reflect your SQL query:

```
for recipe in results:
    output.insert(0, recipe)
```

With a more specific, more meaningful variable name, we can now see the bug. You're actually iterating over result rows from the DB, rather than iterating over individual recipes. So add a comma to fix your syntax:

```
for recipe, in results:
    output.insert(0, recipe)
```

If, for example, the SELECT statement also asked for preparation time, you would use the very same tuple unpacking syntax:

```
for recipe, prep_time in results:
    output.insert(0, recipe)
```

When you see multiple columns being retrieved, the "unpack" may appear a bit more natural to you.

Comment: changing the variable name was a good thought and I have followed the suggestion.  Adding the comma also worked however the item listed in the widget will no longer allow the query to populate the other widget now.
With out the  comma added to that line it populates with the curly brackets on each item and but could click on an item and it would use another query and populate the a widget with the data from the query of the item chosen, but now it will not populate after adding the comma.

Comment: What you're getting at is that `for each_result in results` gives you a *tuple*, while `for recipe, in results` gives you a single string variable. They work differently, so you should decide which you need in each situation. You can go back and forth at will, turning `recipe` into the 1-tuple `(recipe,)`, or perhaps more clearly for you turning a pair of variables into a 2-tuple: `pair = (recipe, prep_time)`. To unpack, do something like: `recipe, prep_time = pair`

Comment: I appreciate the explanation, but I am a little unclear on something.

Comment: Adding the comma changes it from a tuple to a string variable. Where I am confused it when it is a tuple displayed with the curly bracket I can click on of the items and the binding will then query the item in the list and populate the widget. However when the items are a string variable and I click on an item it does not complete the query called from the binding. it give the error:  dish_type_entry.insert(1.0,dish_type_result)       
tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".!entry insert index text

Comment: There must be a way to query a list of items of the same name such as Appetizers from the column in the db and allow it to populate without brackets and still be used to click to perform another query to fetch the corresponding data to that selection.

Comment: ok, so I have experimented with various methods to remove the curly bracket, all will remove them but the item populated in the Listbox can no longer be click on to load the selection. I realize that the query is returning the found items as a tuple and this is why there is curly brackets. I can click on one of the items in the list and it will perform the query to get that data and that works but when I remove the brackets it no longer performs the query to fetch the data for that item. There must be a way to make an item clickable again without the brackets to perform the next query.

Comment: After much trail and error I have found the problem and have fixed this. The issue was in the query initiated by the clicking of the item in the curly brackets, even when removed. When the query was attempted there was an indexing issue and I have since resolved that and the inserted data, now without curly brackets, works perfectly.  Thank you all for the assistance.